# How to Mock context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I like to mock the following to ensure ExecuteNonQuery is called but not sure how to do, as i tried i got may exceptions and could not implement correctly..I am using Rhino Mock

```
using (var command = _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"testproc_ins";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter[] parameters = GetParameters(transaction);
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is how to arrange your code so that you can replace the real object with your mock.  For example:

```
var command = CommandFactory.CreateCommand()
```

And suppose that CreateCommand() in the real CommandFactory is implemented as above, `_context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand()`, but in your unit tests you have a CommandFactory that returns a mock instead.

Once you've done all that, the mock in Rhino is very simple:

```
var cmd = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDbCommand>();
// Somehow pass mock cmd to code under test.  For example,
// CommandFactory here could itself be a mock, and you tell it
// to return the mock cmd you created earlier:
SomeObject.CommandFactory.Stub(c => c.CreateCommand()).Return(cmd);
// Act
// Do something
// Assert
cmd.AssertWasCalled(c => c.ExecuteNonQuery()));
```

Comment: you mean't to say i need to place the _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand() in CommandFactory and mock them . but i don't like to create a CommandFactory class for a single line .

Comment: Welcome to the world of unit testing with mock objects :) It is a pain sometimes but there's no other easy way - you have to somehow inject your dependencies, and your dependency here is the object that creates commands.  Another approach is to provide your own wrapper around _context, so that _context.Database.Connection is under your direct control - but I don't know if that's easier.

Comment: Hi, your second idea worked for me . i wrapped the   _context.Database.Connection  into context class as virtual method so that i could able to control that with mocking . thanks mate.